# Lookup tables in Entity Framework 4.1 (the proper way) in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lookup

With the new release of Entity Framework 4.1, I thought it would be a good time to learn how to utilise it in my coding.  I've started off well but I seem to have hit a brick wall and I dont know what the best approach is.

My issue is when using lookup tables, I cant see how to keep my data as objects (rather than lists, anonymous types etc) when pulling in data from a lookup table.

I have looked around on Google but most of the posts I find are prior to the latest release of EF 4.1 and I am assuming that there is a better way to do it.

I have a simple 'invoice header' and 'customer' situation so I have set the mappings up as you would expect (the invoice header has the Id of the customer it relates to).

If I pull in data from only the invoice table then I get a true object that I can bind in to a datagrid and later save changes but this doesnt pull in the customer name like this, for example:

```
        var results = from c in context.InvoiceHeaders
                      select c;
```

If I restructure the query to pull back specific columns including drilling down in to the customer table and and getting the customer name directly then I get the data I want but it's now not a type of object that I would expect (invoice object), like this:

```
        var results = from c in context.InvoiceHeaders
                      select new { c.CreatedBy, c.Customer.Name };
```

But it now becomes an anonymous type and it seems to lose its bindings back to the database (hope I'm making sense)

So - my question is, "what is the best/official way to use lookup tables in EF 4.1" and/or "can I use lookup tables and keep my bindings"?

Please let me know if you need me to post any code but on this occasion, as it was a general question, I didnt feel I needed to.

Thanks in advance,

James

Answer (score 3):

EF classes are partial so you may expand them :

```
public partial class InvoiceHeaders
{
    public string CustomerName
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return this.Customer.Name;
            }
            catch
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
        private set { }
    }
}
```

But when designing forms, data binding tools does note correctly use this expansion, so you should define a new class and use this class as data source when bind a component to your data source:

```
public partial class InvoiceHeadersEx : InvoiceHeaders
{
}
```

and in form.load event change the binding datasource:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InvoiceHeadersExDataGridView.DataSource = InvoiceHeadersSource;
    InvoiceHeadersBindingSource.DataSource = context.InvoiceHeaders;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this is to make sure you're using `reference objects` (I think that's what EF calls them) in your structure.  So that an Invoice doesn't just have `public int ClientId {get; set;}` but also has `public virtual Client Client {get; set;}`  This gives you a direct link to the actual client- and should still return `Invoice` objects.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Allen.  I am quite new to EF - where would I find the code for what you are telling me?  Is it in the model.designer.cs?

Comment: Take a look at the most recent ASP.NET MVC 3 tutorials- they talk about EF Code First quite a bit, and show usage of reference objects.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I get the problem now.  When you create an anonymous type, it's basically a new class (it has a type definition and everything). Because it's a new type, which you have control over, it's not an EF data type or linked to a data context.

You're best bet is returning the entire customer object.  I appreciate this can cause performance issues when you have large objects, all I can say is, keep your objects smallish.

Comment: Hi Jaimal, please see my updated post for the code examples.  Do you see what I am saying now?  First example keeps the binding but doesn't show customer name where as the second example is visa versa